# Vim doesn't source $MYVIMRC

Tags: vimrc

I thought that setting the environment variable MYVIMRC would make them use that as its rc file on startup, saving me from passing -u every time.

It's set correctly

```
:echo $MYVIMRC
```

shows `/c/Users/me/My Project/.vimrc`

But none of the settings in the file seem to be run.

The file is just two lines rn:

```
set nocompatible
set expandtab tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
```

But vim still uses 8-space-wide tabs instead of 4 spaces

Comment: `:help MYVIMRC`

Comment: Technically, it's `:help $MYVIMRC` but, yes. :)

Comment: I think you may be interested in `VIMINIT` env variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the `MYVIMRC` environment variable does *not* affect what `vimrc` file is used for startup. I think you may have misinterpreted [this bit of documentation](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#.vimrc):

> The $MYVIMRC environment variable is set to the file that was first found, unless $MYVIMRC was already set [...]

This does *not* mean that Vim will use the file found in the `MYVIMC` environment variable if it is set. It just means it won't overwrite the *environment variable* with the location of the file it used if the environment variable already exists.

To manually specify which `vimrc` file to use without using `-u`, instead you can use the [`VIMINIT`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#VIMINIT) environment variable to source the file you want to use:

```
export VIMINIT='source /c/Users/theonlygusti/My\ Project/.vimrc'
```

As an alternative, you could instead use an alias so you still use the [`-u`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-u) mechanism to specify the `vimrc` file, but don't have to type it out every time. e.g. in bash:

```
alias vim="vim -u /c/Users/theonlygusti/My\ Project/.vimrc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add this line to the end of your `.vimrc` file so you have:

```
set nocompatible
set expandtab tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
echom "My file was sourced at ".expand("%")
```

Then close and open vim again. If you dont see that message printing what file location was sourced then its running and its a problem with the settings not the finding of $MYVIMRC.

Within vim try `:e $MYVIMRC` and see the full path of the file it opens up. If it's blank, its loading a different file to what you expect. You can press `2<C-g>` i.e. `2` then `CTRL+g` to see what file it opened. Is that the file you expected, if not see @D. Ben Knoble's comments about `:help $MYVIMRC`.

Comment: :e $MYVIMRC breaks at the first space in its path

Comment: What is the result of `:echo shellescape($MYVIMRC)`? The space should be escaped with `\ `