# Vim not sourcing $MYVIMRC without restarting

Tags: vimrc

At some point which I cannot pinpoint, sourcing `$MYVIMRC` on the fly stopped working.

I tried the solution given here

[Vim doesn't source $MYVIMRC](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26468/vim-doesnt-source-myvimrc)

by typing the following on my terminal: `export VIMINIT='source ~/.vimrc'`

That didn't work.

Changes to my `vimrc` file are reflected once I restart Vim, but not reflected without doing so. Please help.

Comment: It’s $MYVIMRC, not $MYVIRC. What’s the output of `:echo $MYVIMRC` and is your vimrc at that location?

Comment: Just to be clear: the _normal_ behavior is that your vimrc is only sourced once, on startup. You can source it manually or automatically by running certain commands. Perhaps [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) will be helpful

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I *think* they’re saying that `:so $MYVIMRC` doesn’t source the file, but it’s a bit unclear. @Alvaro: could you please clarify?

Comment: @Rich that is correct. Or, at least, `:source $MYVIMRC` is not displaying the behaviour I have come to expect, which is reflecting the changes I make to `vimrc` on the fly.

and `:echo $MYVIMRC` shows `/home/alvaro/.vimrc`, as expected. Apologies for the typo on the main post

Comment: It doesn't seem likely in this case, but it's worth investigating: I saw this once where I had somehow ended up with a `vimrc` in two different locations and i was editing one that was not being sourced. I don't remember how I did it but I was quite irritated with myself when I figured it out.

Comment: Some things to try: 1. What changes are you making? 2. What happens if you replace the entire contents of your file with `echom "test"`? 3. Does it work if you type in the actual file path instead of $MYVIMRC? 4. Does it work if you copy the file to a different location and source that?

Comment: @MDeBusk just checked, this doesn't seem to be the issue.

@Rich I am adding new mappings, i.e. `nnoremap <leader>m`, which, again, works when Vim is restarted, but not otherwise. To your second question, once I source it, test is printed to messages (as you may have predicted). So this pin-points the issue (but I still don't know how to solve it).

3. Had tried it before, didn't work; 4. No, the same behaviour: changes are reflected only after restarting.

Apologies for my delay in replying to you both.

Comment: @AlvaroNeto I'm guessing this issue is long-fixed by now, but just for the record, it sounds like something in your vimrc is causing the lines you've added never to be executed when you re-source the file. Hard to say what that could be without seeing the entire file. As D. Ben Knoble suggested at the time, the techniques described here will help you track down the issue: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/343

Comment: @Rich not so much. I had given up at the time, I will give it another shot some time soon. This is appreciated and bookmarked.